# How do I get a Tata photon VME-102 USB modem working?

Tags: networking, usb-modem

My ubuntu 12.04 is unable to detect my tata photon VME-102 usb model
but the same usb is working fine in windows.
when i use the connection manager to create connection it shows that no usb is connected to the computer.

Comment: Rohan, you can also search the Ubuntu Forums. Here are a few threads from there but I don't use Tata Photon and can't comment about them: [1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1814583), [2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1972943), [3](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1789345), [4](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1782188)

Comment: could you paste the output of **lsusb** both before and after connecting the dongle?

Answer (score 2):

in case you haven't figured it out yet then
here you go....

Steps 1. plug in the modem
      2. run lsusb in terminal
modem is connected as Bus 00x Device 00z: ID 22f4:0021

```
 3.type -    cd /etc/usb_modeswitch.d
 4. type-    sudo gedit

 5. paste the following script
```

#

#############Tata Photon+

#

#############Contributor: Nirbheek Chauhan

DefaultVendor= 0x22f4
DefaultProduct=0x0021

TargetClass=0xff

MessageContent="555342439f000000000000000000061b000000020000000000000000000000"

```
         6. save it as:     /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/22f4:0021
         7. type       cd /
         8. type     sudo usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/22f4:0021
         9. type     sudo usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/22f4:0021
         10. type    sudo usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/22f4:0021
         11.type     sudo usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/22f4:0021
```

open network manager and new cdma broadband connection would be listed there

steps 10 & 11 are repeats of 8 & 9 but that is a way i devised for getting olive v me102 modem to be recognized by ubuntu.

also note that the modem replugging would require the steps 8 and 9 to be performed everytime.

username and password both are internet

P.S. i am just a fellow user not a geek ! pardon me for the above format.

Comment: i tried the above trick but nothing happens after step 7 i get message "no vendor and id provided" what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

The above answer by Shubam works fine for me with a little solution to problem faced by Ankit.

Steps:

1. plug in the modem
2. run `lsusb` in terminal modem is connected as "Bus 00x Device 00z: ID 22f4:0021"
3. `cd /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/`
4. `sudo gedit 22f4:0021`
5. paste the below script in the file

   ```
   ##############Tata Photon+
   #
   #############Contributor: Nirbheek Chauhan

   DefaultVendor=0x22f4
   DefaultProduct=0x0021
   TargetClass=0xff
   MessageContent="555342439f000000000000000000061b000000020000000000000000000000"
   ```
6. save and close the editor
7. `cd /`
8. `sudo usb_modeswitch -p 0021 -v 22f4 -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/22f4\:0021`
9. should show you some product message
10. then at the top right network panel, now you will be able to see Tata Indicom (Photon+) connection 1 (CDMA)
11. click it to connect. now you are successfully connected

Answer (score 0):

You could visit [this link](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/device_reference.txt), where you may find your modem's script and also for other types of newer modems.

Paste them in place of above and voila!